# Convert AM/PM times in pig to 24 hour format

Tags: hive, apache-pig

My source is sending data like 3/13/15 7:54:47 AM. I am loading it as chararray and my final requirement is to use the output of pig in Partitioned HIVE tables (partitioned on Year/Month/Day).

I want to separate h:m:s out of this and need to convert from AM/PM to 24 hour format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ToDate](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date) with a custom date format and then use `GetYear`, `GetMonth` and `GetDay`.

Comment: Thanks Fred! I saw that from another answer on a similar question. How can I take out AM and PM from the string and add 12 hours to the time if it's PM?

Comment: check out http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Comment: Hi Fred, I am having below code HIPS_TEMP = FOREACH HIPS_TEMP2 GENERATE System_Name, '2015-5-03' as Evt_dt; HIPS_TEMP = FOREACH HIPS_TEMP GENERATE System_Name, GetMonth(ToDate(Evt_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as temp_month; But the output always brings "1" for the month's value instead of 5. Do you know why that is?

Comment: use 05 to have 5 as an output of GetMonth

Comment: I did try that as well but no luck